# Update label with Custom Message based on Scale's value, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have an application with only 2 widgets, 1 label and 1 scale.

What I want to do is according to the scale's value update the label's text, so the text would be "Scale's value is (x)" where (x) the scale's value.

I tried to use a common variable when I instantiated the 2 widgets but that's don't help. Any ideas?

```
    firstLine = Frame(root)
    firstLine.pack()

    breakValue = StringVar()
    breakValue.set("Take a break, every 20 minutes")
    workTime = Label(firstLine, textvariable=breakValue)
    workTime.pack(side=self.LEFT)

    workTimeSetter = Scale(firstLine, orient="horizontal")
    workTimeSetter.pack(side=self.LEFT)
    workTimeSetter.set(20)
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @asongtoruin Nothing special, just 2 widgets. I updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a `command` - not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
breakValue = StringVar()

def set_label(val):
    breakValue.set("Take a break, every {} minutes".format(val))

firstLine = Frame(root)
firstLine.pack()

workTime = Label(firstLine, textvariable=breakValue)
workTime.pack(side=LEFT)

workTimeSetter = Scale(firstLine, orient="horizontal", command=set_label)
workTimeSetter.pack(side=LEFT)
workTimeSetter.set(20)

root.mainloop()
```

`command` automatically receives the current value of the scale, hence we can use it in our function.

Comment: wow, I didn't know that command pass the parameter automatically. Thanks, this is what I was looking for!!

Comment: Is it possible to also add your own parameters without messing up it automatically passing it through